# $\Omega^*(M)$ as a graded algebra over the ring of smooth functions. Is there a notion of basis?

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules, graded-algebras

In Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John M. Lee p.360, he defines $\Omega^*(M) =\displaystyle\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Omega^k(M)$, the differential forms on a manifold $M$, as being an associative, anticommutative graded algebra.

My understanding is that this an algebra over the ring of smooth functions $C^\infty(M)$, and not an algebra over the field $\mathbb{R}$.

In graded algebras over a field, each $\Omega^k(M)$ is a vector space, and as such has a basis.

But in our case, all we can say is that $\Omega^k(M)$ is a module over $C^\infty(M)$. I wish I could say, for instance, that I have a basis for $\Omega^1(M)$ given by $dx^1,\cdots, dx^n$. However, since this is not a vector space I am not sure how to make this idea formal, because talking about dimension is not as straight-forward in modules. Is it right to say that $\Omega^1(M)$ is a finitely-generated module over $C^\infty(M)$ (with perhaps the "basis" being $dx^1,\cdots, dx^n$)?

Comment: The differentials $dx^1,\cdots,dx^n$ are, in general, not a global base for the algebra of differentials 1-forms. Instead it is a $local$ base, that is, the restriction of a differential 1-form to the open $U$ in a chart $(U,x)$ (where $x=(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$ are the coordinates for $U$) is the $C^\infty(U)$-linear combination of the differentials $dx^1,\cdots,dx^n$. This means that the sheaf of differentials 1-forms (and differential forms in general) on $X$ is a locally-free sheaf on the sheaf of smooth real-valued functions on $X$

Comment: Also, notice that unless $(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$ is a global coordinate system for the manifold, the differentials $dx^1,\cdots,dx^n$ are not globally defined differential forms, so they are not elements of $\Omega^1(M)$

Comment: In this case, even with a suitable coordinate chart, $\Omega^1(U)$ is not a vector field but a $C^\infty(U)$-module. The only reason we still refer to $dx^1, \cdots, dx^n$ as basis is because the module is free, right?

Comment: Yes, that's why differential forms form a locally-free sheaf. There might not be a base for $\Omega^1(M)$, but there is a cover $\{U_i\}_i$ of $X$ (made by the coordinate charts for $X$), such that $\Omega^1(U_i)$ is a free $C^\infty(U_i)$-module (with basis $dx^1,\cdots,dx^n$), for all $i$

Comment: If you replace the field with a ring in the definition of vector space, you get something called a module. The definitions of linear independence, spanning set and basis still all make sense. The difference is that bases are not guaranteed to exist anymore. Modules admitting bases are called free. Dimension is then called rank. $\Omega^*(M)$ is a free module of rank $2^{\dim M}$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's take the algebra $\Omega^1(M)$ of differential 1-forms (just to simplify the discussion, it's the same for every other $\Omega^k(M)$). First of all, nitpicking: $\Omega^*(M)$ does have a structure making it an algebra over $\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb R$ is a subring of $C^\infty(M)$ (consider the constant functions $M\rightarrow\mathbb R$). In general, if you have a $S$-algebra structure on a module $X$ and a subring $R\hookrightarrow S$, then there is also a $S$-algebra structure on $M$.

Now, as said in the comments, the differentials $dx^1,\cdots,dx^n$ are not globally defined differential 1-forms, but are locally defined. So, if $\{(U_\alpha,x_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ is you atlas for $X$, then each differential 1-form $\omega$ restrict to a differential 1-form $\omega_\alpha=\omega|_{U_\alpha}\in\Omega^1(U_\alpha)$ (for any $\alpha$). Now, for every $U_\alpha$ you have a diffeomorphism $$T^*U_\alpha\rightarrow U_\alpha\times\mathbb R^n$$ (if $x_\alpha$ are coordinates $\phi:U_\alpha\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$) and this diffeomorphism preserves fibers (that is, if $\delta\in T^*_pU_\alpha\rightarrow \phi(\delta)\in\{p\}\times\mathbb R^n$). The diffeomorphism $\phi$ is also fiberwise linear, that is, it induces a linear map $T^*_pU_\alpha\rightarrow\{p\}\times\mathbb R^n$, for all $p\in U_\alpha$. So, composition with $\phi$ induces a $C^\infty(U_\alpha)$-linear isomorphism $$\Omega^1(U_\alpha)\xrightarrow\simeq\mbox{Sections}(U_\alpha\times\mathbb R^n\rightarrow U_\alpha)\simeq C^\infty(U_\alpha,\mathbb R^n)\simeq C^\infty(U_\alpha,\mathbb R)^n$$ so $\Omega^1(U_\alpha)$ is a free $C^\infty(U_\alpha)$-module. the second isomorphism is, i think, clear: A map $\sigma:U_\alpha\rightarrow U_\alpha\times\mathbb R^n$ mapping $p$ into $\{p\}\times\mathbb R^n$ is determined by the composition $$U_\alpha\xrightarrow\sigma U_\alpha\times\mathbb R^n\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb R^n$$ and every map $U_\alpha\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is determined by the $n$-tuple of its components (which is the third isomorphism). In the isomorphism $\Omega^1(U_\alpha)\simeq C^\infty(U_\alpha)^n$, the differential $dx_\alpha^j$ corresponds to the tuple $$(0,0,\cdots,\underbrace{1}_{j\text{th component}},0,\cdots,0)$$where $1:U_\alpha\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the function constant $=1$.

So there you have it: The algebra $\Omega^1(M)$ may not be a free $C^\infty(M)$-module, but there is a cover $\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ such that $\Omega^1(U_\alpha)$ is a free $C^\infty(U_\alpha)$-module. And by the restriction map $\Omega^1(M)\rightarrow\Omega^1(U_\alpha)$ (given by $\omega\mapsto\omega|_{U_\alpha}$, every differential 1-form $\omega\in\Omega^1(M)$ *locally* a $C^\infty(U_\alpha)$-linear combination of the differentials $dx_\alpha^1,\cdots,dx_\alpha^n$, for every $\alpha$